# Python how to input a list of 4 words and "fill in the blanks" to make a sentence

Tags: python

so far I have

```
def attack(words):
     words = ['noun', 'verb', 'adjective', 'place']
     print('Use your', words[2], words[0], 'and', words[1], 'towards the', words[3]+'!')
```

I want to input:

```
attack([shiny, broom, jump, sky])
```

so the sentence should read: Use your shiny broom and jump towards the sky!

but it is printing: Use your adjective noun and verb towards the place!

any ideas what am I missing?

Comment: You are not missing something but there is some extra `words = ['noun', 'verb', 'adjective', 'place']` which will always override your `words` param inside `attack` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this where you index into the input list based on the type of word you need?

```
def attack(words):
     noun, verb, adjective, place = 0, 1, 2, 3
     print('Use your', words[adjective], words[noun], 'and', words[verb], 'towards the', words[place]+'!')
```

Comment: yea your way works too, mines just has less typing to do.

Comment: Had to upvote for accounting for readability @Reblochon Masque.
Always remember The Zen of Python:
Readability counts.

Comment: True. it's just because the instructions advised me to do it a certain way. I like that you presented a different approach that I never thought of. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `words = ["noun", "verb", "adjective", "place"]`.

You are accepting `[shiny, broom, jump, sky]` as the `words` parameter of the `attack()` function and immediately overriding that value by assigning `["noun", "verb", "adjective", "place"]` to a variable of the same name. Additionally, the elements of your `[shiny, broom, jump, sky]` list is missing quotation marks, unless those are meant to be variables and not strings.

Your code should read:

```
def attack(words):

    print("Use your", words[2], words[0], "and", words[1], "towards the", words[3] + "!")

attack(["shiny", "broom", "jump", "sky"])
```

Comment: I'm getting attack([shiny, broom, jump, sky])
NameError: name 'shiny' is not defined

Comment: See my last edit. Unless `shiny`, `broom`, `jump`, and `sky` are variables, you need to wrap them in quotation marks: `["shiny", "broom", "jump", "sky"]`.